# callback for .adjust and .recalc on datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

i want to recalc and adjust my datatable after changing the dimensions of the table by a click event.

Adjusting and recalc the table without a callback works, but the content do a kind of "flipping" so first the old dimensions are visible and after the adjustment it flips to the new dimension. To prevent this, i want to add a overlay or hide the table on the start and show it again if the adjustment has done. At this point i  going crazy.

Heres my code

```
//This works already
$(#mytableid).DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc(); 

//Now i want to add a callback and hide/show the tabele
$(#mytableid).addclass('hide');
//This code failed (also by useing .DataTable)
$(#mytableid).dataTable( {
   "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
     alert( 'now its time to show again' );
     $(#mytableid).removeclass('hide');
    }
} ).columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

I recieved the error DataTables warning: table id=mytableid - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

How i can use a callback for this or may there is another or easier way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3), you cannot reinitialize existing `datatable`. One of ways to do that is to `destroy` existing one and then initialize again -

Working example -

```js
var dataTable = $("#table").DataTable();
dataTable.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
$("#table").hide();
dataTable.destroy();
$("#table").DataTable( {
   "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
     alert( 'now its time to show again' );
     $("#table").show();
    }
} ).columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ok, there is no other way?
I think for reinistalisation i need all information form the first initalization of the table again? In my case this is not easy, this infos comes from another page...Also reinitalization produce unnecessary computing power?

Comment: You can store all options during your first initialization and then reuse on next? According to https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3 changing options dynamically is not possible at all. I am not sure about the performance implications but I think it is more performant to destroy and reinitialize than to change options dynamically. That is why they did not provide this feature. Why do you need to reinitialize the datatable in first place? Maybe there is a work around?